# Is there a more concise way to write this method using Lambda Expressions?

Tags: java, lambda

I'm sorting an array of "Albums" by the output of their method `getAlbumArtist()`, using a custom comparator class, AlphaNumComparator, which has a method `compare`, which compares two strings.

I have the following code, which works:

```
AlphanumComparator comparator = new AlphanumComparator ( CaseHandling.CASE_INSENSITIVE );

Arrays.sort( albumArray, ( Album a, Album b ) -> {
    return comparator.compare( a.getAlbumArtist(), b.getAlbumArtist() );
});
```

This seems like the sort of code that could be simplified/made more clear with some of the new langauge features in Java, but I can't quite make the pieces fit.  Is it possible, or is it about as consice as it gets?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest you to use

```
    Arrays.sort(albumArray, Comparator.comparing(Album::getAlbumArtist, comparator));
```

Comment: You could also use `String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER`.

Comment: That custom comparator does more than just case insensitivity. It also sorts strings with mixed text and numbers in the way a human would. 20 goes next to 19 instead of 2.

Answer (score 1):

Assume the `albumArray` is a `list`, you can do this

```
albumArray.sort(Comparator.comparing(Album::getAlbumArtist, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER));
```

else you can do this

```
Arrays.sort(albumArray, Comparator.comparing(Album::getAlbumArtist, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER));
```